# Shopify - name in variant is null, but others keys are not

Tags: shopify, liquid

Doing this on my Shopify page:

```
{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant | json }}
```

Yields me this JSON output.

```
{
    "id": 22061938375,
    "title": "Small / Black",
    "option1": "Small",
    "option2": "Black",
    "option3": null,
    "sku": "LSL2",
    "requires_shipping": true,
    "taxable": true,
    "featured_image": {
        "id": 14987460807,
        "product_id": 6956222919,
        "position": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-06-24T11:03:47+01:00",
        "updated_at": "2016-06-24T18:17:08+01:00",
        "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1071/2704/products/Lace1-Black-LS-LifeStyle-Shop-R.jpg?v=1466788628",
        "variant_ids": [
            22061938375
        ]
    },
    "available": false,
    "name": "Long Sleeve Chantilly Lace Shimmy - Small / Black",
    "options": [
        "Small",
        "Black"
    ],
    "price": 8800,
    "weight": 454,
    "compare_at_price": null,
    "inventory_quantity": 0,
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "inventory_policy": "deny",
    "barcode": ""
}
```

If I then do: `{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id | json }}` I get: `22061938375` (correct).

However, if I try and grab another key like **name** with this: `{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.name | json }}` I get `null`(wrong).

What on Earth is going on here? Why can I only access some keys and not all of them, even though I can see them in the full output? It's not making much sense to me.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that "name" is not actually a member of [variant](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/variant). I'm guessing that the "name" that appears in the JSON output is dynamically generated. It is simply the concatenation of the product title and variant title.

Also using the JSON filter for this is overkill. 
You can do

```
{{ product.title }} {{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.title }}
```

if you know that the product has options or something like:

```
{% assign currVar = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
{{ product.title }}{% unless currVar.title contains 'Default' %} {{ currVar.title }}{% endunless %}
```

Comment: I wish Shopify would document this stuff. What's the use in putting it into the object if it cannot be used directly? Weird. Thanks for your help. I built it manually as you suggested. I was only using the JSON filter for debugging purposes.

Comment: Note the variant link in my answer. The objects available for Liquid are pretty well documented. The function of the json filter not so much.